# Grabbing specific values from JSON

Tags: json, ruby

So here is what i'm trying to do. I'm building a simply Ruby file that will as the user for input, a city, and then return weather results for that city. I've never written in Ruby nor have I ever used API's. But here is my attempt.

The API response below:

```
> {"coord"=>{"lon"=>-85.68, "lat"=>40.11}, "weather"=>[{"id"=>501,
> "main"=>"Rain", "description"=>"moderate rain", "icon"=>"10d"}],
> "base"=>"stations", "main"=>{"temp"=>57.78, "pressure"=>1009,
> "humidity"=>100, "temp_min"=>57, "temp_max"=>60.01},
> "wind"=>{"speed"=>5.17, "deg"=>116.005}, "rain"=>{"1h"=>1.02},
> "clouds"=>{"all"=>92}, "dt"=>1475075671, "sys"=>{"type"=>3,
> "id"=>187822, "message"=>0.1645, "country"=>"US",
> "sunrise"=>1475062634, "sunset"=>1475105280}, "id"=>4917592,
> "name"=>"Anderson", "cod"=>200} [Finished in 2.0s]
```

The Ruby file below:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=anderson&APPID=5c89010425b4d730b7558f57234ea3c8&units=imperial'
uri = URI(url)
response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
parsed = JSON.parse(response)
puts parsed #Print this so I can see results
inputs temp = JSON.parse(response)['main']['temp']
puts desc = JSON.parse(response)['weather']['description']
puts humid = JSON.parse(response)['main']['humidity']
puts wind = JSON.parse(response)['wind']['speed']
```

What I was trying to do was only pull out a few items like temperature,description, humidity, and wind. But I can't seem to get it right. I keep getting undefined errors with each attempt.
(Wanting to complete this without using gems or anything that isn't already built into Ruby) (I have not written the parts for user input yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that response['weather'] is an array, so you won't be able to access ['weather']['description'], instead you will have to do something like ['weather'][0]['description'].

```
2.3.0 :020 > puts parsed['weather'][0]['description']
moderate rain
2.3.0 :021 > puts parsed['main']['humidity']
100
2.3.0 :022 > puts parsed['wind']['speed']
5.17
2.3.0 :025 > puts parsed['main']['temp']
58.8
```